# what is update_against_templates in pootle 2.7?

Tags: python, django, pootle, translate-toolkit

I added a new template file from my project. Now I don't know how to make the languages update or get the new template file. I've read that 2.5 has update_against_templates but it's not in 2.7. How will update my languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template updates now happen outside of Pootle.  The old `update_against_template` had performance problems and could get Pootle into a bad state.  To achieve the same functionality as `update_against_templates` do the following.  Assuming your project is `myproject` and you are updating language `af`:

1. `sync_store --project=myproject --language=af`
2. `pot2po -t af template af`
3. `update_store --project=myproject --language=af`

You can automate that in a script to iterate through all languages.  Use `list_languages --project=myproject` to get a list of all the active languages for that project.